# Redirecting without change of address in browser address bar

Tags: redirect, dns

I have a different but similar question. I have a dynamic dns account where I map my machine's dynamic IP to an address say, **www.xxx.yyy.net**

Now, I have registered another short domain name say **www.yyy.com**, the hosting is on a linux server.

Now, my machine is actually a webserver which runs .net website which can be accessed by **www.xxx.yyy.net** I need my homepage(index.php) in my **www.yyy.com** handle the redirection in a way that the pages to be loaded from **www.xxx.yyy.net**/.... but it should look in the browser as **www.yyy.com**/...

Is there any way to do this using php?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is an easy way. If you are using Apache you can write a .htaccess with some rewrite rule in it to to a transparent redirect.

Comment: can you please explain this a little more? Bcoz, I am a beginner in terms of apache and php.